# Prevent Enter key works as mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I noticed that if you focus on an element that mouse clic can be triggered, the Enter keys acts like as you left click the mouse. I want to avoid this running since it comes into conflict in other pieces of my code.

In the following example if I focus on this imageButton and I clic once, the next clicks can be "done" with the Enter key, so I don't want this because this button fires a slideToggle() and shows a hidden div, so IMO it's pointless toggle this div with the keyboard.

[image]

Is there any way to make it **global way**?
Thank you.

Comment: Listen for `"keypress"` and `.preventDefault()`

Comment: @PaulS. this should be an answer I think

Comment: Preventing this action may be frustrating for the users of this application, since it is a common behavior. I suggest you find an alternative system to your buttons. (This is just a suggestion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".myElements").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

It will stop the <kbd>enter</kbd> key behaviour only, allowing the other key functions to work as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Listen for `"keypress"` and `.preventDefault()`

ex. with `<myelm class="nokey"/>`

```
function noKeyPressing(){
    var elms = document.getElementsByClassName('nokey'),
        stop = function stop(e){ return e.preventDefault(), false; },
        i = elms.length;
    while(--i >= 0){
        elms[i].addEventListener('keypress', stop, true);
    }
}
noKeyPressing()
```

If you just want to prevent <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the keyCode to look for is 13.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.unbind('keydown');
```

to disable all key events on your element

Answer (score 0):

You can return false to prevent the default action.

```
  <input type="submit" onkeypress="return false;" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    $('body *').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

the above code will prevent pressing enter for every element in page
,You can change the selector `$('body *')` to something else depending to your case

Answer (score 0):

An other possible way i think:

```
$('.elems').on('click',function(){$(this).blur()});
```